# How to reload a listview

Tags: jquery, html, listview, kendo-ui

I have listview in the pager of a span it calls a function that reloads the listview. What happens is that it works in chrome but not working in IE or Firefox:
this is my code

```
<div id="listView"></div>
                    <div id="pager" class="k-pager-wrap">
                        <a href="#" id="Refresh" class="k-link" onclick="Refrescar()">
                            <span id="btnRefresh" title="Refrescar" class="k-icon"></span>
                        </a>
                    </div>
```

and this is the function:

```
function Refrescar() {
    var listView = $("#listView").data("kendoListView");
    listView.refresh();
}
```

Comment: kendoListView? Do you use kendo ui? If yes then you should add it to your tags.

Answer (score 0):

`.dataSource.read();` this will reload the data. Bare in mind this re fetches the data whereas refresh() only refreshes the data on screen. Works in IE for me.